# Replace part of a string (an HTML code) with /n line break for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, textarea

I have a form with textarea. When I add the info from the form to the DB, I replace the /n line break from that textarea with a < br> tag, like that:

```
$("#distributor_address").attr("value").replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

It displays correctly when I need to present it as HTML text. However, if I want to edit the data and I pull it from the DB to place again in text area, that's exactly how I see it:

```
line 2 < br> line 1
```

(I must mention that the direction of my page is set to: rtl)

No line break. I tried to reverse it like that:

```
var dist_address = result[0].distributor_address;
dist_address = dist_address.replace('<br>', /\n/);
$("#distributor_address").val(dist_address);
```

But that's how I see the result:

```
line 2/n\/line 1
```

So how can I reverse that < br> tag back to line break in the textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dist_address = dist_address.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
```

The `g` modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed it replaced it all, tested it also with 3 lines and it worked great! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dist_address = dist_address.replace('<br>', '\n');
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DHkUh/)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
dist_address = dist_address.replace('<br>', '\n');
```